# aliases are not used for @AspectJ aop style

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an aspect defined in the following way:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class SomeAspectDefinition {

  @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && bean(someBeanAlias)")
  private void pnct() {
  }

  @Around("pnct()")
  public Object aroundPnct(ProceedingJoinPoinbt pjp) throws Throwable {
    return pjp.proceed();
  }
}
```

and in context file:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

However `someBeanAlias` can not be resolved and thus proxy is not created for bean behind `someBeanAlias` alias.

I checked code and this happens due to missing `beanFactory` in `org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.BeanNameContextMatcher.matchesBeanName`. It seems that this factory is only set through `BeanFactoryAware` interface which is not used when pointcut is created manually in `org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AbstractAspectJAdvisorFactory.createPointcutExpression(Method, Class, String[])`.

Am I missing something or it is a bug?

I use `spring 3.2.5`

Comment: This works fine for me. Can we see your bean declaration and its aliases and how you are component scanning?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Spring user, but a quick search shows me that this problem should have been fixed since 2.5.3. Maybe you want to comment on or reopen the ticket or maybe create a new one pointing to the old one:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4601

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your scenario and not even in Spring 2.5.3 (the version SPR-4601 has been fixed for) it doesn't work with @AspectJ style.

On the other hand, though, it does work in xml (all versions from 2.5.3 to 4.0.4):

```
    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="aliasAdvice">
            <aop:pointcut id="pnct" 
                expression="execution(* *(..)) &amp;&amp; bean(someBeanAlias)" />
            <aop:around method="around" pointcut-ref="pnct" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

For the time being, if possible you could use the xml approach. And a new JIRA issue against Spring I think will not hurt.